# Laravel's querybuilder select where id is not into another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got two tables here `subscriptions` and `school` and I want to select only the schools that are not subscribed yet. I referenced the schools `id`. Can someone help me with this in laravel's querybuilder?

My current code

```
  $schools = \DB::table('schools')
                          ->leftJoin('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.school_id', '=', 'schools.id')     
                          ->select('schools.*','subscriptions.status')
                          ->get();
    dd($schools);
```

Schools Table

```
+----+------+-----------------+
| id | name | description     |
+----+------+-----------------+
|  1 | SAFE | Safe University |
|  2 | MND  | DEMO UNIVERSITY |
|  3 | Test | Test 1          |
|  4 | X    | Test 2          |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

Subscriptions table

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| id | school_id | start_date | end_date   | plan_id | status |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 |         1 | 2019-10-20 | 2019-11-30 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |         2 | 2019-09-27 | 2019-10-27 |       1 |      0 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+---------+--------
```

When i `dd` I get the 4 schools

```
Collection {#796 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#762 ▶}
    1 => {#799 ▶}
    2 => {#803 ▶}
    3 => {#839 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `whereNotIn` to get schools which is doesn't exist in another table.

```
DB::table('schools')
    ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('subscriptions')->pluck('school_id'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried it but it is the reverse of what i need. I get the two schools who are subscribed.

Comment: use `whereNotExists` for that check updated answer.

Comment: i got this error sir `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereNotExists() should not be called statically`

Comment: try updated answer.

Comment: wow thanks for your answer. Can you please explain it to me so that i can understand??

Answer (score 1):

You can define relationship of Schools and Subscriptions:

In your `School` model define relationship

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription','school_id'); // path of Subscription model
}
```

Query to get schools which have subscriptions:

```
$schools = School::with('subscriptions')->doesnthave('subscriptions')->get();
```

Comment: how to do it in querybuilder sir?

Comment: for query builder you can use @Laravel answer

Comment: Perfect way with a relationship. Thanks, @YasinPatel for appreciate for query builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$schools = \DB::table('schools')
                          ->leftJoin('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.school_id', '=', 'schools.id')     
                          ->select('schools.*','subscriptions.status')
                          ->whereNull('subscriptions.school_id')
                          ->get();
    dd($schools);
```

Comment: i got an empty result sir